# How to do A = A + B kind of operation in SharePoint Calculated column?

Tags: calculated-column

I have to create a calculated Column "A" for which the formula would be something like this

```
=IF(SomeCondition = True,[A] + [B],[A])
```

However on trying this I am getting following error

> The formula contains a circular reference (the calculated column refers to itself).  You must remove or change the circular reference.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What are you trying to do? A=A+B makes no sense in the context of a ROW of data.

Comment: Thanks for ur response....well i m trying to add to or retain the previous value of the calculated column based on some condition....nd also i did'nt understand "A=A+B makes no sense in the context of a ROW of data"...can u elaborate a bit?

Comment: Play with this on Excel as it will be clearer. You can't do in cell A1 the formula =A1+B1 - it doesn't make sense, there is no way to 'retain the previous value'. Same as in normal algebra - this is not a procedural programming language. So again - explain the business requirement behind this and there may be another way.

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?

Your current calculation checks if `TRUE == TRUE` and if so returns `[A] + [B]`, otherwise `[A]` (but that can never happen since TRUE is always TRUE)

[This Office documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA001160947.aspx) is really helpful for finding example calculations to modify. But if you clarify exactly what output you would like (prefferably with an example) we can help you easier.

Comment: Thanks for ur resoonse...Well what i m trying to do is IF(SomeCondition == True) Set A = A + B Else Don't change A

Answer (score 0):

Calculated column doesn't have a value outside the formula, so using it as a part of assigning itself a value makes no sense.

Please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks for ur response....well i m trying to add to or retain the previous value of the calculated column based on some condition

Comment: I don't think you can and I don't think calculated column is meant to be used like this.